# What is starting date for real time clock?

Tags: windows, date-time

Windows [uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time) January 1, 1601 as starting date.

What does Real time clock use?

If it uses different starting date, does Windows convert its timestamp(because it [uses](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232488) its date and time) into its own? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RTC clock saves its time in battery-backed CMOS memory (nowdays it's just a more integrated chip that emulates older designs). CMOS Memory map is pretty standard on PC-compatible computers. According to these [CMOS memory map docs](http://CMOS%20Memory%20Map):

```
 00h Seconds       (BCD 00-59, Hex 00-3B) Note: Bit 7 is read only
 01h Second Alarm  (BCD 00-59, Hex 00-3B; "don't care" if C0-FF)
 02h Minutes       (BCD 00-59, Hex 00-3B)
 03h Minute Alarm  (BCD 00-59, Hex 00-3B; "don't care" if C0-FF))
 04h Hours         (BCD 00-23, Hex 00-17 if 24 hr mode)
                         (BCD 01-12, Hex 01-0C if 12 hr am)
                         (BCD 81-92. Hex 81-8C if 12 hr pm)
 05h Hour Alarm    (same as hours; "don't care" if C0-FF))
 06h Day of Week   (01-07 Sunday=1)
 07h Date of Month (BCD 01-31, Hex 01-1F)
 08h Month         (BCD 01-12, Hex 01-0C)
 09h Year          (BCD 00-99, Hex 00-63)
```

So it is a straight calendar math to convert these fields to whatever format you fancy: Unix timestamps, DOS-type date/time format, or whatever.

Note that one field lacking from the map above is the time zone and DST setting. So, if you're dual-booting into say Windows and Linux you might have problems. Windows defaults to your local time zone, while Linux usually assumes RTC date/time is UTC (which is more sane in my opinion).

Comment: Yeah, I wish Windows would switch to local time. But you can only imagine the sheer amount of applications this would break.

Comment: @surfasb: Windows can use UTC for the RTC (feature existed in NT 4.0, later added again in 7), and absolutely no program will care. The primary [reason](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/02/224672.aspx) it doesn't is to avoid breaking multi-boot setups and OS upgrades.

Answer (score 3):

It seems (from [osdev](http://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#The_Real-Time_Clock) and [Linux `arch/x86/kernel/rtc.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/rtc.c#L104)) that the RTC on Intel x86 platform keeps the datetime as separate values for second, minute, hour, and so on.

> To get each of the following date/time values from the RTC, you should first verify that Status Register A is not in "update mode" (Bit 7, value = 0x80 is clear). Then select the associated "CMOS register" in the usual way, and read the value from Port 0x71.

```
Register   Contents
   0       Seconds
   2       Minutes
   4       Hours
   6       Weekday
   7       Day of Month
   8       Month
   9       Year
  0x32     Century (usually)
  0xa      Status Register A
  0xb      Status Register B
```

The contents of all these registers are converted to a NT or Unix timestamp using advanced mathematics (i.e. addition and multiplication). For a Linux example, see [`kernel/time.c:mktime`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/time.c#L303) in the kernel source.

```
return ((((unsigned long)(year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + 367*mon/12 + day) + year*365 - 719499)*24 + hour)*60 + min)*60 + sec;
```

Also, the MSKB article you linked is somewhat out-of-date. Starting with XP, Windows doesn't check the RTC every hour; it uses NTP instead, and *writes to* the RTC.

Answer (score 0):

a 'Timestamp' (mostly in *nix systems, or any C-like language) usually means the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970

Comment: i meant timestamp in general, e.g. certain amount of units since certain starting date.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy: As I understand it: "What timestamp format does the hardware clock use, and what date would an all-zeros timestamp represent?"